# Disable Logging from DriverManagerDataSource

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbc, properties, connection, log4j

I want to filter this log out from my daily log file. 
Example Line:

```
"09-12-2013 05:16:06 [DEBUG] http-8080-2 (DriverManagerDataSource.java:getConnectionFromDriver:162) Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection."
```

And my Log4j.properties file is

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF 
log4j.logger.com.lhub = DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina.home}/logs/E-Attendance-logs/myapp.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true 
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss} [%5p] %t (%F:%M:%L) %m%n
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in your file the next line:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource=OFF
```